# The noun use of the word "Aimer"

Tags: vocabulaire

I came across the word "aimer" in french language.

I saw few sentences having this word and got to know that it means "to like" in the context of objects and as "to love" in the context of persons .

But I found the usage of the word as a verb so I was wondering if this word "aimer" can also be use as a noun .

Are there sentences where the word "aimer" has been used as a noun or can this word be used as a "noun" in sentences which mean like "the love that they had " or "the love of life "

The noun form corresponding to aimer, that I found, is "amour", are there any other words which mean the same as "amour" but in a more general context like " the love for all the people " , " the sense of love towards other" ?

Answer (score 2):

*[Amour](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/amour)* is not the only substantive that can be used when referring to *aimer*.

There is another direct derivative, *[amitié](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/amiti%C3%A9)*, which is to *amour* a little bit like what "to like" is to "to love" but only applies to person to person relationship (friendship) when *amour* might be too strong or ambiguous. There is also a stronger but lost substantive: *[amativité](http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/amativit%C3%A9)*.

In all other cases, *amour* can always be used (*son amour pour les chats*, *l'amour du jeu*, *l'amour des choses bien faîtes*) but we might also use softer alternatives like *[attachement](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/attachement)* (e.g. *son attachement pour les chats*) and *[goût](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/go%C3%BBt)* (e.g. *le goût des choses bien faites*).

To translate "the love for all the people", we might use:

> *L'amour du prochain / pour son prochain* (usually in a religious context.)
>
> *L'amour d'autrui / pour autrui* (ditto, expression probably a little outdated.)
>
> *L'[amabilité](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/amabilit%C3%A9)* (another *aimer* derivative, the quality of someone who is kind to everyone)

Answer (score 1):

"Aimer" is never used as a noun. As you pointed out, "amour" is the noun form, and while there are definitely [synonyms](https://dictionnaire.reverso.net/francais-synonymes/amour), there is not, in French, any strict nuance between the "generic" love of somebody,  the very specific love for your partner or the "love" of some generic things or concept.

Answer (score -3):

"aimer" is a verb. and "amour" is special, it can change its gender when set to plural. "des amours passées"
https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluriels_irr%C3%A9guliers_en_fran%C3%A7ais

**you can find love as a noun** to despict a significant other in old litteracy: "mon aimée" to speak about a woman you love. not to be mistaken by "ma mie", which has a similar meaning, but sounds like "mamie", which means grandma.

you can speak about love of some abstract thing, then love is also a noun:

> "l'amour de la peinture"
>
> the sense of love towards other : "un amour partagé/réciproque"

Comment: "Aimer" is never a noun, always a verb. The noun is "amour" . I actually don't think this answers any of the questions of OP

Comment: *Des amoures* ???

Comment: my bad, "des amours" had a typo, it is feminine when plural but does not have an "e" in the end